# Optimal radiator sizes?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, power, technology

Imagine a situation where we need to generate 10 GW of electrical power for about an hour. It would probably require large equipment, which would also produce waste heat. Lets further imagine that this is happening in space and there is vacuum around, thus it becomes harder to get rid of waste heat.

I'm wondering if it could be possible to cool such apparatus with radiators and what the minimum reasonable area of such radiators would be using best current technology?

I suspect the radiator temperature should be as high as maintainable for maximum radiated heat yet it contradicts that the cold end of a heat engine should be kept at minimum for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Stefan–Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) $$A= \frac{P}{\sigma T^4}$$
where $T$ is the desired maximum temperature and $P$ is the waste power.

Comment: This would give me the minimum necessary area at maximum possible temperature, yet coefficient of efficiency for heat engines is proportional to the difference of temperatures at hot and cold end. If I choose the maximum temperature, that certain materials could withstand, this would lead to poor engine performance resulting in more waste heat. I am curious about the minimum possible area. Would combining both functions and deriving it lead me to the answer?